# Create a callback function within a custom jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure how to approach this as I am fairly new to jQuery. I'm wanting to create a callback function within a custom function. Here's my example:

```
function doSomething() {
    var output = 'output here';
    // Do something here

    // This is where I want to create the callback function and pass output as a parameter
}
```

I want the callback function to be accessible by any number of scripts (e.g. more than one script can access this callback).

This function (doSomething) is not part of a plugin but rather part of another callback function itself. I've also created a var within the function and want to pass that through the callback function as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you're saying you don't have control of what is passed to `doSomething`? Depending on what framework your using that may not be true... can you share the code where you pass `doSomething` as a callback?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I won't necessarily know what is being passed into doSomething, but it needs to be available for someone to come in and extend.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you're asking.  Creating a callback function is as simple as declaring a function and passing it as an argument to another function that is expecting a callback.

```
function doWork(fnCallback) {
    // do some work
    // when done with the work
    // call the callback
    var someVar = 1;
    fnCallback(someVar);
}

function myCallback(val) {
    alert("got my callback - val=" + val);
}

doWork(myCallback);
```

Or, using an anonymous function instead of a named function

```
doWork(function(val) {
    alert("got my callback - val=" + val);
});
```

If you really want to declare a function within a function, you can do that too:

```
function doSomething() {

    function myCallback(val) {
        alert("got my callback - val=" + val);
    }
    doWork(myCallback);
}
```

Comment: The first example looks like what I want to achieve, but can that callback function be called multiple times? So, say you load 3 scripts on the page and each script wants to hook into that callback using myCallback. Will there be issues with calling myCallback 3 times?

Comment: @Thomas - `myCallback` is just a regular function.  You can call it as many times as you want.  Functions are made to be called - that's their point in life.  There is no difference between a function used as a callback and a regular function - they are the same thing.

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted to know. I wasn't sure if the process was **defining** a new function or just **calling** it - that's where I was confused, because I know you can't define a function more than once, but you can certainly use it more than once. Thanks for clearing that up for me!